# Extract the base object from the dependent one

Tags: c#, oop

I have a base class and a dependent one.

```
class A
{
   ...
}
class B : A
{
   ...
}
```

How could I extract the object of the base class from the dependent one?

```
B myDependant = new B();
A myBase = (A) myDependant;
```

`(A)` casting is optional, but `myBase` object is still type of `B`. I want `myBase` to be the type `A` without creating a new object.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your `myDependant` has all capabilities of `A` class, you can pass it as an argument to methods accepting `A` and do every other thing you would do with `A` object.

Comment: Can you edit classes `A, B` ?

Comment: Why would you like to do this ? B is of type A so no need to create an A object ...

Comment: It is unclear what you are hoping to achieve. Please describe the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: can you be more obvious, the b class is already type of A because of inheritance,I don't understand

Comment: I need myBase object of type A because I would need to serialize this object to the json directly. If myBase object is type of B I have more properties but I cannot serialize it directly.

Comment: The base class is not a part of the descendant. If you need an instance of the base class, you need to create an instance of the base class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can create your own contract resolver that will check whether the property belongs to certain type and if not, it will mark it as ignored:

```
class MyContractResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        var baseProps = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in list)
        {
            prop.Ignored = baseProps?.All(p => p.Name != prop.PropertyName) ?? false;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
var myDependant = new B();

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver<A>() };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDependant, settings);
```

The pros here is that your class will only be serialized once and cons is that in case when A inherts from other class - its properties will be serialized as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment, you can do something like this:

```
B myDependant = new B();
A myBase = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDependant));
```

In this way the `myBase` will be an instance of the `A` class as you want.